# How to check whether a class is stateless?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a container, and want to only allow stateless allocators for it. From various sources I figured that such allocator should be an empty class, and should be trivially constructible, copyable and destructible. However, std::allocator has user-provided default constructor (though, with empty body) and thus fails to pass `std::is_trivially_constructible` check. Is there any way to check if user-provided constructor has empty body, or, if not, to set other criteria for "stateless"?

Comment: Why do you want only stateless allocators? Can you test for what you really want instead of assuming you get what you want from "stateless"?

Comment: Isn't "empty" == "stateless"? I don't think non-trivial operations make it stateful?

Comment: Explain your real world example. That would help you get a good answer.

Comment: Swap operation, for example. For `container<Ty, Alloc1>`, swapping with `container<Ty, Alloc2>` where allocators have different states becomes rather complicated.

Comment: @Lenassa Wouldn't having allocators of different types be a bigger problem than having state? How would you guarantee that an object of type `Alloc1` knows how to deallocate the memory obtained by the first container via this swap (even if the allocators are stateless)?

Comment: @JaMiT `Alloc1` and `Alloc2` have the same type, but different states, sorry if I made that unclear. It makes it hard to write templated code since stateful ones may or may not have methods to checking or changing state, but there are no standards which describe these. C++ standard has the requirements that can be considered a baseline of a sort.

Comment: @Lenassa You may want to assume people use the standard containers as a reference point. For example, `std::vector<T, A>` is a vector whose elements are of type `T` and whose allocator is of *type* `A`. If you are going to deviate from the pattern of the standard library, you should not rely so much on people guessing what your symbols represent.

Comment: @Lenassa So... if `Alloc1` and `Alloc2` are the same type, your usecase does not care so much about the objects being stateless, as much as it cares if the type is [swappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable). So a more refined check would be to see if the type of the allocator [is swappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_swappable), rather than checking for being stateless. *A container should not be responsible for the logic of how to swap allocators. That task is for the type of the allocators.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_empty) to check if a type has no non-static data members and no virtual functions, which would mean it has no state.

Comment: So, emptiness is enough? Because boost documentation, for example, says that their method checks for "trivialness".

Comment: I believe so, if it has no data members it can only have global state.  The only way I see non-triviality being a problem is if there's logging (or something similar) in its constructors.